# Can't login to MediaWiki right after installation

Tags: centos, mediawiki

When Installing latest stable MediaWiki on A CentOS machine I created a user and a password with my email as part of the `LocalSettings.php` file that the installer creates.

After the installation wizard finished I downloaded the `LocalSettings.php` file and uploaded it to the site's directory.

I then navigated to MediaWiki site in my browser by the website's domain.

- When I try to login I get an error message that the credentials for my user are wrong.
- When I try to retrieve password to my email my username isn't recognized.
- I also tried a capitalized version.

Why is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a browser caching issue. After I closed the browser tab and opened another and got into the website anew, I could then login.

It might be that I totally closed the browser window --- I didn't notice if I closed it in between using the different tabs. I think I didn't close the browser window.

In either case I didn't refresh the page F5 or CTRL+R or CTRL+F5 and similar.

Comment: That's definitely not a browser caching issue. Could be an issue with the server-side cache in MediaWiki (the admin user not being available yet or being in some half-created state) although it seems unlikely. But it's impossible to debug that without way more details (what cache backend you use etc), especially if it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Thanks, you might want to make this an answer somehow and I'll gladly accept.